# Why does TextEditingController crash on some devices?

Tags: android, flutter, crash, textfield

I have a very simple app in which there is a form where the user types a phone number, and the app calls an API to get the orders this number has made in a restaurant ou store. Well, on some devices as soon as the form is shown and the user touches the text field, the app crashes without any warning, just goes off the screen. This does not happen in various emulators, nor in a vast number of devices, but it does in some of them (unfortunately one of them is of the guy who paid for the app...). This is the code of the form:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:nascenterio/dialogs.dart';

import '../global.dart';

class PhoneScreen extends StatefulWidget {


  PhoneScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PhoneScreenState createState() => _PhoneScreenState();

}

class _PhoneScreenState extends State<PhoneScreen> {

  final TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode phonefocusNode;
  String myPhone;

  @override
  
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myController.text = glbPhone // global variable to init the field value;
    phonefocusNode = FocusNode();
    phonefocusNode.requestFocus() ;
  }
    @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    myController.dispose();
    phonefocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: glbAppBarColor,
        title: Text("Meus Pedidos"),
      ),
      body:
        Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center ,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: myController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                  focusNode: phonefocusNode,
                  autofocus: true,
                  onEditingComplete: () {
                    if (myController.text.length >= 8) {
                      Navigator.pop(context, myController.text);
                    } else {
                      aviso(context,"O número do telefone deve ter pelo menos 8 dígitos.");
                    }

                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Número do telefone (pelo menos 8 dígitos)',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                color: glbAppBarColor,
                child: Text("Pesquisar",
                style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white),) ,
                onPressed: () {
                  if (myController.text.length >= 8) {
                    Navigator.pop(context, myController.text);
                  } else {
                    aviso(context,"O número do telefone deve ter pelo menos 8 dígitos.");
                  }
              },)
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

As can be seen, this form does not access the API, it just returns the number typed in the TextField.
I'm not a Flutter expert, and maybe there is some configuration or reference I should be using to overcome the problem.
By the way, one of the phones on which the app crashes has an x86-64 architecture, if it helps.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would suggest, that you implement crashlytics, so you would get the actual error that was causing the crash. Alternatively, if you can get in touch with a phone that actually crashes, read out it's logs to get the error. The only thing I see which seems odd is, that you requestFocus on a focusNode, which at the moment triggered, is not even built. If you want, that the keyboard opens, you should put this into a WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) { //HERE }) , so it is executed after the the first build completed.

Comment: I suggest reading about [global error handling in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors). You can wrap your app in a handler that catches all errors and then send those errors to a server where you can store them and look at them to investigate what went wrong.